# How can I write to HDFS from Spark to make access to that data faster?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

Assume that I am not tools like Hive or HBase (Spark is unable to use Hive indexes anyway for optimization), what is the best way to write data to the HDFS to make access to that data faster.

What I was thinking is to save many different files, the name of whose is identified by the keys. Let us say we have a database of people who are identified by their firstname and surname. Maybe I could save files with the first letters of firstname and surname. In this way, we would have 26x26=676 files. So, for example, if we want to see record of Alan Walker, we need to just load the file AW. Would this be a good way or are there much better ways to do this kind of thing?

Comment: You can create HDFS partitions for the first letters of names, sure, but those queries would look weird... It does not dictate *number of files*, though. In general, more partitions means more files, and if there isn't enough data within a given partition (less than the block size), then you're wasting processing resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that an index is what you need. In HDFS as in databases indexing has some overhead on insertion but makes queries much faster.

HDFS does not have any sort of index as it is supposedly a DFS rather than a Database, yet the requirement that your mentions has been implemented through third programs

There are many *indexing tools* that works with HDFS, you can have a look to **APACHE SOLR** for instance

Here is a tutorial to keep you going: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/running-solr-on-hdfs.html